# How to write MySQL query to find foreign key entity exists?

Tags: mysql, sql, liquibase

I need to update the customer details in my table

If client_id exists in the client table and client_id exists in customer table I will update if not insert, using the following query

```
INSERT INTO `customer` (`username`, `password`, `client_id`) 
VALUES ('username', 'password', 1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `password` = 'user-password';
```

I need to skip update and insert when client_id is empty(id not present in client table).

How to write MySQL query to skip this?

Comment: > is for quotes. For multiline code indent with four space (which can be done with the {} button.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **REPLACE** instead of **INSERT**. If the PRIMARY KEY exists, it would replace the row, but if not, then it would do the insert as usual.

```
REPLACE INTO `customer` (`username`, `password`, `client_id`) 
VALUES ('username', 'password', 1);
```